# Get security for folder (s) in iManage with c#

Tags: imanage

I know how to get security attributes for items in a folder for Imanage. I am looking for some code snippet that gives me security attributes only at the folder level.

Answer (score 2):

The `IManFolder` type has a `Security` property that contains both `UserACLs` and `GroupACLs` properties for a folder. You can find out existing user and group rights by going through these collections.

As an example, the code snippet below adds the existing user rights from myfolder onto the `IManDocument` newDoc.

```
foreach (IManUserACL acl in myfolder.Security.UserACLs)
{
  newDoc.Security.UserACLs.Add(acl.User.Name,acl.Right);
}
```